# useContext to pass data from A

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I am trying to pass data from a JSON file to a component with useContext:

```
import sessionData from '../session.json';

import React from 'react';

export const SessionContext = React.createContext(sessionData);

export const SessionProvider = SessionContext.Provider;
export const SessionConsumer = SessionContext.Consumer;

console.log('session data', sessionData); //console log ok
```

Next I am passing it into a class component

```
  static contextType = SessionContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    const sessId = this.context;
    console.log('steps', sessId); // log ok
  }


  render() {
         return <SessionProvider value={sessId}> //value returns undefined.
                    <Child A />
                    <Child B />
                    <Child C />
               </SessionProvider>;
         }
```

In the first two code blocks shown, my data returns fine. Now I want to pass it to the child components (which are functional component). However, when I try to pass a value to the session provider `<SessionProvider value={sessId}`, the value returns as undefined.

I've seen other examples where the value is passed directly into the component like ``{sessId.name}`. However, if I'm just trying to make` sessId``` available to all the child components.

Answer (score 0):

### sessId doesn't exist

The error that you're getting is likely that `sessId` doesn't exist.

`sessId` exists in the `componentDidMount` method but not in your render method.

You would need to create that variable in your render method with `this.context`, just like you did in `componentDidMount`.

### You don't need the provider

But... you don't need the provider there. When you provide an initial value to `React.createContext`, then that becomes a default value, so you can just consume it with the children and the data will be there.

### You don't need context

However, if you're just using static JSON, then you don't need context here at all: just import the JSON file into each of the children and use it there.